# Two classes have the same XML type name, Error in Windows but not Linux

Tags: linux, windows, web-services

Environment:

- JBoss 6
- Windows 7
- Java 6

> ERROR
>
> [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController]
>   (Thread-2) Error installing to Real: name=vfs:...
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException:
>   org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
>
> ...
>
> Two classes have the same XML type name "{...}dictionary". Use
>   @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to
>   them.

I have this problem, when I work with windows, but it suprisingly works on linux with the same environment.

The difference with the state before, it was that we added a jar module in some pom's instead of having the classes in a local module.

**POM modification**

```
<jarModule>
    <groupId>groupid.name</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactid-name</artifactId>
    <includeInApplicationXml>false</includeInApplicationXml>
    <bundleDir>lib</bundleDir>
</jarModule>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Are the names *exactly* the same including case?

Comment: Exactly the same code, each compiled with its respectively JVM

Comment: It was a long shot, but as Linux is case sensitive, but Windows isn't I thought there might be something there.

Comment: thanks I'll take a look of that